# Generators for Fuchsian 1-holed torus groups in terms of Fenchel–Nielsen coordinate

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

Let S be a hyperbolic 1-holed torus with a geodesic boundary of length $\ell$.

How can we write down the generators for Fuchsian groups associated with S in terms of Fenchel–Nielsen coordinate? And what is the formula for these groups?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, we can, but it will be quite ugly.

Comment: I got $\Gamma=\bigg\langle \begin{bmatrix} x+y&-xy(xy+1)\\xy+1&-xy(x+y)\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} t&xy\\1&x+y-t\end{bmatrix}\bigg\rangle$ where $0<x<y<1$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is the formula in your comment intended to be part of the question? If so, you should edit the question to include the formula and to include whatever it is that you want to ask concerning that formula. But I'll add that it will be impossible to use that formula to verify that there is a geodesic boundary of length $\ell$, because $\ell$ is not even a parameter in the formula as it is currently written.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: The formula intended to be the answer I found after asking the question a few days. It is not a complete answer, I forgot to ask a condition on x and y which is $\frac{x+y}{xy+1}=\tanh(\frac{\ell}{4})$. But this formula is not in terms of Fenchel-Nielsen coordinate. I think it will be quite ugly if we rewrite it in terms of Fenchel-Nielsen coordinate.